# Memory friendly image hash

Tags: android, image, hash, bitmap

I'm downloading pictures of unknown size from the internet and check, if the image was changed compared to the image I downloaded the last time.

For doing this, I calculate an image hash and remember that hash.

```
String currentContactHash = 
    ImageFunctions.getPictureMd5Hash(bitmapTmp, false, errorContactHash);
String currentInputHash = 
    ImageFunctions.getPictureMd5Hash(bitmapToUse, true, errorInputHash);
```

This sometimes fails because of an `OutOfMemoryError`... I can't control the size of the image from the web, but I need a hash of it.

Here are my `ImageFunctions`:

```
public static byte[] convertImageToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap, boolean compress)
{
    if (compress)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }
    else
    {
        int bytes = ImageTools.getByteCount(bitmap);
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
        return buffer.array();
    }
}

public static String getPictureMd5Hash(Bitmap bitmap, boolean compress, BooleanHolder error)
{
    error.set(false);
    try
    {
        return getInternalPictureMd5Hash(bitmap, compress);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e)
    {
        error.set(true);
        return null;
    }
}

private static String getInternalPictureMd5Hash(Bitmap bitmap, boolean compress) throws OutOfMemoryError
{
    if (bitmap == null)
        return null;

    byte[] bitmapBytes = convertImageToByteArray(bitmap, compress);

    String s;
    try
    {
        s = new String(bitmapBytes, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        L.e(Updater.class, e);
        return null;
    }

    MessageDigest m = null;

    try
    {
        m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {
        L.e(Updater.class, e);
    }

    m.update(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length());
    return calcHash(m);
}

private static String calcHash(MessageDigest m)
{
    return new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16);
}
```

Does anyone have an improvement suggestion for that?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to get a hash of the decoded image data itself? For your purposes, a hash of the compressed format data will be fine, and be much quicker to produce since it deals with a lot less data..

I'm guessing that you are caching the image data to file (though caching to a database works as well).  From that you can get the data back as an input stream, at which point the standard code to produce a digest serves you just fine:

```
MessageDigest digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
int byteCount;
while ((byteCount = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
  digester.update(bytes, 0, byteCount);
}
byte[] digest = digester.digest();
```

Comment: Actually, I use `Picasso` to get the two images (the one from the server and the current one from the phone)... So both images are in memory as bitmaps, when computing the hash... But the splitted digest function would be a improvement itself, I think

Comment: btw, splitting the digest function does really make the thing slow... I will use 1MB instead of 1KB... Testing on my phone shows a speed difference of about 100 times (although my images are all smaller than 1MB), I would estimate... Though, your example helped me, I think, this will solve my problem, I just have to test it...